# Flash a error/success message on flask after .validate_on_submit

Tags: python-3.x, flask, web-applications, visual-studio-code

Newbie to Flask and a very short time to learn to do something decent(College).
I have a survey that I would like to use FLASH to flash the success and error messages(category), though I haven't been able to do so, I gave it a good research and I did get how it works, my code seems fine comparing to the examples I have found, but it is clearly not. If someone could please help me out, it would be much appreciated.

This is the .py file

```
def index():
    form = Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(u'Thank you for your collaboration!', 'success')
        if not form.validate_on_submit():
            flash(u'Something went wrong!', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    #submission_successful = True #or False. you can determine this.
    return render_template('index1.html', form=form) #submission_successful=submission_successful)
```

the .html file

```
<center>
    <form methods='POST'>
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:200px; class="form-field"> {{ form.Email.label }} <br> {{ form.Email }}  </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.sex.label }} {{ form.sex }}   </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.age.label }}  {{ form.age }}  </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.Marital.label }}  {{ form.Marital }}  </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.county.label}}  {{ form.county }}  </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.Property.label }}  {{ form.Property }}  </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.PropertyStatus.label }}  {{ form.PropertyStatus }}  </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.Rooms.label }}  {{ form.Rooms }}  </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.People.label}} <br> {{ form.People }} </div> <br>
        <div style = font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:100px; class="form-field"> {{ form.submit}}  </div>

        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                {% if category == 'success'%}
                    <div class='alert alert-success mb-3' role='alert' >
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                {% if category == 'error'%}
                    <div class='alert alert-danger mb-3' role='alert' >
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}


    </center>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple template using flash messages...customize this for Ur case

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for,session, flash
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import (StringField, SubmitField)


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'


class InfoForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('What are you?')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Create instance of the form.
    form = InfoForm()
    # If the form is valid on submission (we'll talk about validation next)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Grab the data from the breed on the form.

        session['name'] = form.name.data
        flash(f"You just changed your name to: {session['name']}")
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<div class="container">


  {# get_flashed_messages() is auto sent to the template with the flash() call #}
      {% for mess in get_flashed_messages()  %}
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" class="fade close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{mess}}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}


<form method="POST">
    {# This hidden_tag is a CSRF security feature. #}
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name() }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Man you have been a live saver. I got the setup for it, I will adjust for my code. Thanks. As soon as it works I will mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do for message flashing. 
https://hastebin.com/behopumivu.cs
Sorry formatting is bad I am phone. But if you would put this in your base template, when you do “flash” it will always flash a message at the top of whatever page the user is currently on. Hope this helped!